# How do I display menu items in front of images?

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal navigation menu and when you hover over the menu, the items display behind the images on the webpage as opposed to in front of. How would I fix this?

CODE: http://jsfiddle.net/MvWkZ/

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Photoshop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Illustrator</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">User Experience</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}

#nav ul {
background: #efefef; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 20px;
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
}

#nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

    #nav ul li {
float: left;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
    #nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

#nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
}

    #nav ul ul {
background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
    #nav ul ul li a {
        padding: 15px 40px;
        color: #fff;
    }   
        #nav ul ul li a:hover {
            background: #4b545f;
        }

                    #nav ul ul ul {
position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

Comment: Post your code. And try `z-index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use the z-index css attribute :

```
.horizontalmenu{
     z-index:10; /*or more than your image */
     position:relative;
 }
```

Post some code if you want a more precise answer

Edit : As said by Don in comments, be sure to put your menu in position:relative (edited css)

Comment: It should be noted that `position: relative` needs to accompany and `z-index` settings

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `z-index=1` (or any number that is higher than the images) for example in the css for the menu. Hope this helps :)